# Numerical solution for free quantum particle

Tags: schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, simulations, fourier-transform, software

I'm struggling with finding another approach for numerically simulating the free quantum particle (with cyclic boundary conditions). I have made a short document on this:

https://github.com/Ch3shireDev/PyQuanta/blob/master/PyQuanta.ipynb

In short - standard, working approach to simulating Psi function is to add evolution as an exponent of wave numbers multiplied with Psi in it's frequency representation in space. In short, it looks like this:

$$\psi(t+dt) = ifft(exp(-ik^2 dt/2)\cdot fft(\psi))$$

Which is great - $\psi$ function is complex, Fourier transform is great for differentiating cyclic complex functions etc. The problem is - I want to describe $\psi$ function as two real functions - in my main intention as $Re^{i\theta}$, but for now - only as $\psi = f+ig$. And, sadly, I don't have any working solution which wouldn't blow functions to infinity and would give any similar results. I'm desperate and I'm asking for help. Could you show me any good working methods for numerical differentiation of functions?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the question, you need both $\Psi(x,t)$ and $\partial_t \Psi(x,t)$, right?

Comment: Yes. I add $\partial_t\Psi\cdot\Delta t$ to $\Psi$ to obtain time evolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

$$
\psi(x, t) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}k~ e^{2\pi i k x}\hat{\psi}_k(t)
$$

such that the equation

$$
i\partial_t\psi(x, t) = -\frac{1}{2}\partial_x^2\psi(x,t)
$$

becomes

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}k~\left[i\partial_t \hat{\psi}_k(t) + \frac{1}{2}(2\pi i k)^2 \hat{\psi}_k(t)\right] e^{2\pi i k x} = 0
$$

from this you can conclude that

$$
\partial_t\hat{\psi}_k(t) = -2i \pi^2k^2 \hat{\psi}_k(t) \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

with solution

$$
\hat{\psi}_k(t) = e^{-2i\pi^2 k^2 t}\hat{\psi}_k(0) \tag{2}\label{2}
$$

So to calculate $\psi(x,t)$ use $\ref{2}$ and to calculate its derivative use $\ref{1}$. Below there's small code to do this

```
def propagate(dt, x, psi):

    k = np.fft.fftfreq(x.shape[-1], x[1] - x[0])

    f1 = np.fft.fft(psi)
    f2 = np.exp(-2j * (np.pi * k) ** 2 * dt)
    psik = f1 * f2

    psi = np.fft.ifft(psik)
    dpsi = np.fft.ifft(-2j * (np.pi * k) ** 2 * psik)

    return psi, dpsi
```

You can test it with

```
x = np.linspace(-0.5 * L, 0.5 * L, num = n)
s = 0.05 * L
psi0 = np.exp(-0.5 * (x / s) ** 2) / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * s * s) + 0j

# propagation
psi1, dpsi1 = propagate(0.1, x, psi0)
plt.plot(x, np.abs(psi0), 'b-')
plt.plot(x, np.abs(psi1), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I was looking for a method to calculate separately real and imaginary part of psi. This method I know and use. Thanks anyway.